# Program package to work with all the Linux distribution

Tags: linux, package, libraries, symlink

I'm currently working on a Linux project. This project needs to run under every Linux distribution (without installing any package/libraries/others for the clients) and it's a bit hard to do it well.

I already tried to do it myself, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29675285/c-program-compiling-with-glibc-and-not-the-default-libraries-permission-denied/29719270), i have also tried to use [CDE](http://www.pgbovine.net/cde.html) but it didn't work well since i got an error with some distribution. For example:

- Ubuntu 8.04: Impossible to read the header ELF
- Debian 7.8: version of GLIBC_2.14 not found

So, i would like to know if there is a way to get a package of my program who can run under every Linux distribution.

Thanks

Edit: I would like to avoid the static compilation, since my program is pretty big.

Comment: The best what you can is to compile your program statically (do note that the binary can then have several hundreds of MB). This still won't guarantee that the binary will run across all distributions, as such requirement is ridiculous.

Comment: Well, there is also an option to distribute the sources with clang and compile on-site. But that will have other issues with missing headers and such.

Comment: You don't want to install any libraries and you don't want to compile statically... There's a saying about eating your cake and having it too.

Answer (score 0):

There are big differences between linux distributions, especially version of libraries and package management system.

The only way how to do it is to build/compile your project against all libraries you need to use statically, and distribute them with your project.

For example skype and ejabberd do it this way.